# How to filter out logging in Serilog with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serilog

I want to information to the log in my web app. Seems like it would fall under the `Information` category.  The problem is that if I set the default logging level to `Information`, the .NET Core itself will write stuff to the log file that I don't want there.

I have the following:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Is(logLevel)
               .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "{Date}.txt"))
               .CreateLogger();
```

Is it possible to create a logger where I only write my own events to.  This applies to any .net core compatible logging frameworks out there.

Or do I need to roll my own custom class for this?

Comment: Just don't register this logger with .NET Core? That way you can have two different loggers: one for .NET Core (with a higher minimum level) and one for your own application code.

Comment: Change the MinimumLevel line with this one `.MinimumLevel.Debug()`

Comment: @Hackerman Then it will log absolutely everything.

Comment: @mason Do you have an example?